# Cytoscape 3.8.2; Transitivity Clustering in ClusterMaker2 does not work

Tags: cytoscape

When I run Transitivity Clustering from clusterMaker2 in Cytoscape 3.8.2, it stops at the very beginning, and the task manager writes "Caught exception executing task".

It also happens when I try partitioning the network in the link below, where the Authors used TransClust for their work

http://www.plantphysiol.org/highwire/filestream/123923/field_highwire_adjunct_files/1/253807File_S3_FlowerNet_cytoscape_without_main_view.cys.zip

Any idea of what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry!  It's a bug that's been on my plate for fix for some time.  There will be a new release of clusterMaker2 this summer and I'll make sure to fix it for that release.

-- scooter